# How to use variables in imagesLoaded callback function?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, imagesloaded

I'm trying to do something very simple, but I'm obviously doing something wrong. Here is the code:

```
var targets = Array(
    $('.someDiv'),
    $('.myDiv')
    );
// This "for" loop check if the Class exists and if so it runs a code
for (var i = targets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // make the target a jQuery object
    var $target = targets[i];
    // if the target exists
    if ( $target.length > 0 ) 
    {
        console.log($target);
        // run some code after every image is loaded
        $target.imagesLoaded( function()
        {
            console.log($target);
            $target.addClass('blue');
        });
    }
}
```

which somehow doesn't work.
The JsFiddle example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w8mk7eqd/1/)

Is it just impossible to pass a variable without hacking imagesLoaded plugin? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `myVar` is `undefined` because it's undefined.

Comment: Yes, the example wasn't that accurate. See now what I meant.

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wayav6u8/). Please provide an example of it not working.

Comment: Ok, I updated the example with the real one. You can see it also [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w8mk7eqd/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the variable to retain the value it had when calling `imagesLoaded()`, you can use an IIFE:

```
var myVar = 'someContent';

(function(myVar) {
    $('.myDiv').imagesLoaded( function() {
        console.log(myVar);
    });
})(myVar);
```

Take this example:

```
var myVar = 'some content';

(function(myVar) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(myVar);
    }, 1000);
})(myVar);

myVar = 'some other content';
console.log(myVar);
```

It will log `some other content` and then, a bit later `some content`, as was the initial value.

Comment: It should, unless some part of the code sets the variable to `null` while loading the images.

Comment: Why would that happen?

Comment: I don't think OP has posted his entire code, so just `myVar = null;` would do this. Consider this JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/wayav6u8/1/

Comment: I didn't know about the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Thanks a lot. That method solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Good news:* Your code works!

```
var myVar;
$('.myDiv').imagesLoaded( function() {
    console.log(myVar);
});
```

`myVar` is `undefined` as you did not define it.

... try `var myVar = "Hello World";`

Comment: Yes, sorry, my example was misleading. It's that 'Hello World' that doesn't get through...

Comment: :/ ... if you are using it in global-space it should work

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `imagesLoaded` callback is fired *after* you have already iterated over the elements. Which means that by the time the first callback is fired, `$target` is a reference to the last element in the array.

Fortunately, since you are just trying to get a reference to the element that `imagesLoaded` was called on, you can get a reference to it with `this`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4uyf2o2z/)

```
var targets = [$('.someDiv'), $('.myDiv')];

for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    var $target = targets[i];

    if ($target.length) {        
        $target.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        });
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use the `$.each()` function in order to store the context on each iteration:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/n7bnww6q/)

```
var targets = [$('.someDiv'), $('.myDiv')];

$.each(targets, function (i) {
    var $target = targets[i];

    if ($target.length > 0) {
        $target.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $target.addClass('blue');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @Arg0n solved it, but this is more elegant as a solution. Thank you both.